# In PowerPoint VBA, animation does not work with a freeform shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PowerPoint VBA, I want to create a FreeForm shape and then add an animation effect to it.
This works fine with Dim as Shape, but I need it to be a FreeForm which causes an error.
Many thanks and best wishes.

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Dim myLines As FreeformBuilder

Set myLines = myDocument.Shapes.BuildFreeform(EditingType:=msoEditingCorner, X1:=50, Y1:=50)

With myLines
.AddNodes SegmentType:=msoSegmentLine, EditingType:=msoEditingCorner, X1:100, Y1:=100
.ConvertToShape
End With

With myLines.AnimationSettings
.Animate = msoTrue
.EntryEffect = ppEffectAppear
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.

We need to convert the FreeForm into a Shape object.

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Dim myLines As FreeformBuilder
Dim myLinesShape as Shape

Set myLines = myDocument.Shapes.BuildFreeform(EditingType:=msoEditingCorner, X1:=50, Y1:=50)

With myLines
.AddNodes SegmentType:=msoSegmentLine, EditingType:=msoEditingCorner, X1:100, Y1:=100
.ConvertToShape
End With

myLinesShape = myLines

With myLinesShape.AnimationSettings
.Animate = msoTrue
.EntryEffect = ppEffectAppear
End With
```